# Testing asynchronous capabilities of a django + tornado application

Tags: django, unit-testing, asynchronous, tornado

I'm using [django-on-tornado](https://github.com/koblas/django-on-tornado) to build an application that is similar to the chat applicatoin proposed. All tutorials are focused on how to run a django application over tornado server, but how can I test an asynchronous feature that depends on tornado?

My current test does the following:

- Starts a thread that sleeps for some time than sends a chat message
- Do a request to ask for messages
- When request ends, check that message arrived and that time elapsed is compatible with thread sleep time

When I run the test (with manage.py test), I get an "AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute '_tornado_handler'", which is expected, since the _tornado_handler property of the request is set in runtornado command.

Is there a way to make this setup so that I can test the asynchronous feature? I use nose with django_nose plugin for tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually django-on-tornado does not anyhow change the **manage.py test** command of Django, so the Tornado is invoked only via **runtornado**. You will need to add command to manage.py called something like "testtornado" with implementation similar to https://github.com/koblas/django-on-tornado/blob/master/myproject/django_tornado/management/commands/runtornado.py - it should set up _tornado_handler and proceed with launching your test code.